# Modifying a copy/paste item in Outlook prior to save (C#)

Tags: c#, .net, plugins, outlook, copy

I recently wrote an Outlook plug-in (for use in Outlook 2010) for a client that syncs up their user's Outlook databases with a third-party application.  This works fine.  However, one thing that the client wants to do is to leverage standard copy/paste functionality to duplicate records in Outlook.  The issue is that I define a UserProperty for any Outlook record that has been sent to the third-party system (it stores the internal ID from the third-party system).  When the client performs a copy/paste, this UserProperty is also copied (which is bad as it creates multiple records with the same third-party ID).  I was wondering if there was some way to detect via code that a copy/paste was occurring and to make a modification in the record (removal of this UserProperty) prior to save.  As they might perform this on Tasks, Appointments, or Contacts, I would need guidance that would apply across the board.

Per the suggestions below, I attempted to leverage BeforeItemPaste, as seen below:

```
private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e) {
    Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveExplorer().BeforeItemPaste += new Outlook.ExplorerEvents_10_BeforeItemPasteEventHandler(Item_BeforeItemPaste);
}

private void Item_BeforeItemPaste(ref System.Object ClipboardContent,
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MAPIFolder Target, ref bool Cancel) {
    System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Trying to paste");
}
```

The message appears the very first time I do a copy/paste, and then never again.  I tried leveraging Application.Explorers, which theoretically gives me access to all Explorers in Outlook, but that didn't give me access to the individual ones (Appointment, Task, Contact) that I was looking for (there was only one element in that 'array' when I debugged it).  Also, I tried to access those specific Explorer items by invoking MAPIFolder.GetExplorer, but this always returned null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use Explorer.BeforeItemPaste event.

Comment: From the code posted above, my problem appeared to stem from the fact that I didn't declare a separate 'null' Explorer variable outside of ThisAddIn_Startup.  Once I did that, and then set that equal to this.Application.ActiveExplorer() within ThisAddIn_Startup, I got it to trigger each time.  Thank you Dmitry for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: One other item to mention - it turns out that you can't actually modify the item to be pasted, because it doesn't exist yet.  The only thing you can access is a reference to the original object.  Thus, if you make changes to it, you'll modify the original.  To get around this, you basically have to short-circuit the system.  Access the selected object, copy it, set Cancel to true, and then modify the copied object and save it.  From the user's point of view, copy/paste still happens.

Comment: Be careful with ThisAddIn_Startup - there might not an Explorer yet (or ever - e.g. when you click a mailto link and only an Inspector comes up). You might also want to hook up the Inspectors.NewInspector event.